# How to implement oauth2 to external api in meteor app

Tags: api, meteor, oauth-2.0

I'm writing, beacuse i'm having trouble trying to implement a method to auntenticate oauth2 in a meteor APP (using react in view). In this case i have to connect to my own autentication server running in .net. I have read some tutorials with facebook, github, etc, but in my case is different

Anyone have any code, tutorial or know how to implement?.

Thanks

PD: i'm new using Meteor.

Answer (score 0):

There is a meteor package for OAuth2 here

https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/oauth2

It doesn't provide much information, except directing you to the Meteor accounts documentation at https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html

There is also this page, which provides examples of both client and servers for OAuth2. I haven't explored it myself, but it looks like a good start. I always like to look at examples myself when picking up something new :)

https://github.com/prime-8-consulting/meteor-oauth2